# Aspose export without Ms excel

Tags: excel, import, export-to-excel, aspose-cells

is it possible to generate a worksheet like excel on a machine where Excel is not installed.

Currently I am using Aspose.Cells **ImportDataTable** function but it requires Ms Excel as a pre-req. Is there any way that it can be done on a machine where MsOffice is not installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid, your understanding is not correct. Aspose.Cells APIs are built using managed code that do never need Microsoft Office or Microsoft Excel to be installed on the machine to work with its features or manipulate Excel document formats. It should be Microsoft Office automation alternative and an independent library.

Note: I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.